# Rename files with zero padded numbers while keeping extension using "rename" command

Tags: command-line, rename

I want to rename files with zero padded numbers while keeping extension.
Example
a.abc
b.cde
c.xyz

to be renamed as
001.abc
002.cde
003.xyz

```
:~/x$ rename -n -v 's/.+/our $i; sprintf("%03d.jpg", 1+$i++)/e' *
#output>
rename(a.abc, 001.jpg)
rename(b.cde, 002.jpg)
rename(c.xyz, 003.jpg)
#then
:~/x$ echo "a.abc"
a.abc
:~/x$ echo ${_##*.}
#output>
abc
so I tried>
:~/x$ rename -n -v 's/.+/our $i; sprintf("%03d.${_##*.}", 1+$i++)/' *
Global symbol "$i" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $i"?) at (user-supplied code).
Missing right curly or square bracket at (user-supplied code), within string
syntax error at (user-supplied code), at EOF
```

Any suggestions using ***"rename"*** command?

Comment: You're trying to stuff the shell variable expansion `${_##.*}` into perl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rename -n -v 'our $n; my $zn=sprintf("%03d", ++$n); s/[^.]*/$zn/' *
```

This would probably do what you intended. Instead of putting the Perl code *inside* the substitution, we run it *before* the substitution.

The regular expression `[^.]*` would match any length string up to (but not including) the first dot in the filename.

To match up to the *last* dot, use `.*\.` instead, and insert the dot on the replacement side:

```
rename -n -v 'our $n; my $zn=sprintf("%03d", ++$n); s/.*\./$zn./' *
```

Note that this would also rename directories.

---

Alternatively, using a simple shell loop, assuming you would want to enumerate the files in the order they are expanded by the `*` shell glob, and that you use `bash`:

```
n=1
for filename in *; do
    [ ! -f "$filename" ] && continue
    zn=$( printf '%03d' "$n" )
    mv -i -- "$filename" "$zn.${filename##*.}"
    n=$(( n + 1 ))
done
```

This additionally skips any name that does not refer to a regular file (or a symbolic link to one). Apart from that, it follows *very closely* the Perl `rename` variation above in that it keeps a counter (`n`) and a zero-filled variant of the counter (`zn`).

The variable `n` is a simple counter, and `$zn` is has the same value as `$n`, but as a zero-filled three-digit number.

The value of `$zn.${filename##*.}` would expand to the zero-filled number, followed by a dot and the final filename suffix of the original filename.  If more than one dot is present in the original filename, everything up to the *last* dot will be replaced by the zero-filled number.  Change `##` to `#` to replace up to the *first* dot.

This assumes that you run the loop on files in the current directory only.

Comment: @VeeJay Read again.

Comment: Sorry I was on mobile didn't read properly. Made my day.

Comment: Rename command-lines are perfect. Please check the mv cmd, it didn't work. Out put `mv: overwrite '001.abc'? ` after first file.

Comment: @VeeJay Ah, thanks for that. I thought I simplified the code, but in fact I broke it. Now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
rename -n -v 'our $i; s{^\./.+?(\.[^.]*)?\z}{sprintf "%03d%s", ++$i, $1}se' ./*
```

- `./` prefix in `./*`: needed for some variants of `rename` that would fail otherwise for filenames starting with `-`.
- `.+?`: match at least one character, as we don't want a leading `.` (for hidden files, only relevant if the `dotglob` option of your shell is enabled) to be considered as an extension separator.
- `(\.[^.]*)?`: also rename files without extension (like `.foo` or `foo`)
- `\z`: match end of the subject. More generally with `rename`, you don't want to use `$` as it matches either at the end of the subject or before a trailing newline.
- `s` flag: make sure `.` also matches a newline character which is as valid as any in a file name.
- `e` flag: the replacement is a perl expression, so we can use `sprintf` there.